# Website won't scroll right or left on Mobile

Tags: css, html

I designed a website. Everything works on desktop but on mobile, it is not scrolling right or left. When I open the browser on my mobile, it is showing one-third of the website and won't let me scroll to the right. What is the problem and how do I fix this?

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background-color: #f9cbdf;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/webtreats_baby_pink_pattern_21.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from `#container`.

When `overflow: hidden;` is used the overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

The default value for `overflow` is `visible`.In this case, the content is not clipped

If `overflow` is set to `auto`, the browser decides whether to clip or not.

See more about `overflow` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `overflow:scroll , check the example

```css
.overflow{
width:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='overflow'>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</div>
```

`if you want to let the users scroll all sides and if you want only x axis use`overflow-x:auto;`and for y`axis overflow-y:auto;`